# How secure is hosting a node.js personal app on 127.0.0.1? Can it be accessed anywhere other than my own computer?

Tags: networking, security, node.js

I have a node.js app for personal purposes hosted at 127.0.0.1

```
server.listen(80, '127.0.0.1', function() {...
```

It contains sensitive information.

As I understand only me (computer that is currently running the said node.js process) will be able to access it. Is that 100% true? Or could it be accessed even by someone on my LAN, or worse from outside internet?

Comment: While what Marcelo said, that you can only access it from localhost if it's bound to 127.0.0.1, is true, you can in some cases be tricked into accessing the site and divulging the information it contains to outside entities. See [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) for general info and [Breaching the Breach Browser](https://blog.liftsecurity.io/authors/adam-baldwin) for a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is a loopback address. If the process is bound to only that address, then it can only be accessed from that machine.

Note that a process can be bound to multiple addresses, so run a `netstat -ano` (Windows) or `netstat -npla` (Linux) to verify what ports are open and to which process.